# Writing of decimal numbers with Kanji?

Tags: numbers

As an example, I want to write the decimal number 3.78
Is it common to write it as 三.七八 with Kanji?
What about 点? Is 三点七八 being used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that, when the text is written horizontally, kanji numerals won't be used normally.

Regardless of text directions, it seems the norm is to use [・(なかぐろ)](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%AD%E9%BB%92) .

[This page](http://www5d.biglobe.ne.jp/Jusl/Bunsyo/Suujihyouki.html) quotes 「記者ハンドブック」（第8版：1997年共同通信社刊）

> ２．数字は、特別の場合を除いて、洋数字を使う。
>
> (1)数字のケタは、千、百万、十億で区切り、その符号として「，」を使う（小数点の「・」を使うのは間違い。）

So 3.78 will be written 三・七八.